# How to generate XML using Builder to loop over structures inside XML

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

The original post was a mess, hope this edit is clearer!.

I am looking to generate XML from hashes, nested inside arrays. I have attempted to use Nokogiri builder and cannot quite get it right. Thanks to some help from Tin Man I am now a little closer, but my example was nowhere near clear enough to be deciphered. I also missed out some key information.

This is the XML that I need to generate:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Report Tool="FirewallParserv1">
      <Firewalls>
        <Firewall>
          <issues>
            <issue id="1" Category="2">
              <Data mode="table">
                <Row>
                  <column>ACL</columnumn>
                  <column>Rule</column>
                  <column>Source</column>
                  <column>Dest</column>
                  <column>Service</column>
                  <column>Log</column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <column>inside_access_in</column>
                  <column>1</column>
                  <column>10.10.10.1</column>
                  <column>192.168.1.2</column>
                  <column>SMTP</column>
                  <column>YES</column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <column>inside_access_in</column>
                  <column>2</column>
                  <column>172.16.2.1</column>
                  <column>192.168.100.10</column>
                  <column>HTTP</column>
                  <column>NO</column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <column>inside_access_in</column>
                  <column>3</column>
                  <column>172.16.2.200</column>
                  <column>10.10.60.1</column>
                  <column>TELNET</column>
                  <column>NO</column>
                </Row>
              </Data>
            </issue>
          </issues>
        </Firewall>
      </Firewalls>
     <Firewalls>
        <Firewall>
          <issues>
            <issue id="2" Category="2">
              <Data mode="table">
                <Row>
                  <column>ACL</columnumn>
                  <column>Rule</column>
                  <column>Source</column>
                  <column>Dest</column>
                  <column>Service</column>
                  <column>Log</column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <column>outside_access_in</column>
                  <column>8</column>
                  <column>195.92.195.92</column>
                  <column>192.168.1.2</column>
                  <column>SYSLOG</column>
                  <column>YES</column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <column>outside_access_in</column>
                  <column>9</column>
                  <column>8.8.8.8</column>
                  <column>192.168.100.10</column>
                  <column>SSH</column>
                  <column>NO</column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <column>outside_access_in</column>
                  <column>10</column>
                  <column>172.16.3.200</column>
                  <column>10.10.90.1</column>
                  <column>PROXY</column>
                  <column>NO</column>
                </Row>
              </Data>
            </issue>
          </issues>
        </Firewall>
      </Firewalls>
    </Report>
```

So far I have gotten close with the following code, but the nested loops are meaning I end up with too many iterations/repetition of each 'issue', three to be precise.

```
rule_array1 = [
  {:id => '1', :aclname => 'inside_access_in', :Rule => '1', :Source => '10.10.10.1',   :Destination => '192.168.1.2',    :port => 'SMTP',   :Log => 'YES'},
  {:id => '1', :aclname => 'inside_access_in', :Rule => '2', :Source => '172.16.2.1',   :Destination => '192.168.100.10', :port => 'HTTP',   :Log => 'NO'},
  {:id => '1', :aclname => 'inside_access_in', :Rule => '3', :Source => '172.16.2.200', :Destination => '10.10.60.1',     :port => 'TELNET', :Log => 'NO'}
]

rule_array2 = [
  {:id => '2', :aclname => 'outside_access_in', :Rule => '8', :Source => '195.92.195.92',   :Destination => '192.168.1.2',    :port => 'SYSLOG',   :Log => 'YES'},
  {:id => '2', :aclname => 'outside_access_in', :Rule => '9', :Source => '8.8.8.8',   :Destination => '192.168.100.10', :port => 'SSH',   :Log => 'NO'},
  {:id => '2', :aclname => 'outside_access_in', :Rule => '10', :Source => '172.16.3.200', :Destination => '10.10.90.1',     :port => 'PROXY', :Log => 'NO'}
]

array_of_arrays = rule_array1, rule_array2

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Report('Tool' => 'FirewallParserv1') {
    array_of_arrays.each do |outer|
      outer.each do |rule|
          xml.Firewalls {
            xml.Firewall {
              xml.issues {
                xml.issue('id' => rule[:id], 'Category' => '2') {
                  xml.Data('mode' => "table") {
                    xml.Row {
                      xml.column("ACL")
                      xml.column("Rule")
                      xml.column("Source")
                      xml.column("Dest")
                      xml.column("Service")
                      xml.column("Log")
                    }
                    outer.each do |rule|
                      xml.Row {
                        xml.column(rule[:aclname])
                        xml.column(rule[:Rule])
                        xml.column(rule[:Source])
                        xml.column(rule[:Destination])
                        xml.column(rule[:port])
                        xml.column(rule[:Log])
                      }
                    end
                  }
                }
              }
            }     
          }
      end    
    end
  }
end

puts builder.to_xml
```

How do I loop within the loop and only return the correct number of 'issues'? There should be two, each with three rules, each taken from one of the nested arrays of hashes as per the XML example.

I hope the question is now clearer and apologies for the mess in the original.

**Update: So I managed to hack together basically what I wanted:**

```
issue_id = 1
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
    xml.Report('Tool' => 'FirewallParserv1') {
      xml.Firewalls {
        xml.Firewall {
          array_of_arrays.each do |outer|
            xml.issues {
              xml.issue('id' => issue_id, 'Category' => '2') {
                xml.Data('mode' => "table") {
                  xml.Row {
                    xml.column("ACL")
                    xml.column("Rule")
                    xml.column("Source")
                    xml.column("Dest")
                    xml.column("Service")
                    xml.column("Log")
                  }
                  outer.each do |rule|
                    xml.Row {     
                      xml.column(rule[:aclname])
                      xml.column(rule[:Rule])
                      xml.column(rule[:Source])
                      xml.column(rule[:Destination])
                      xml.column(rule[:port])
                      xml.column(rule[:Log])
                    }
                  end
                }
              }
            }
            issue_id +=1
          end    
        } 
      }
    }
end


puts builder.to_xml
```

To get there though, I had to abandon accessing the :id value from the hash, as I don't access that hash until I start the `outer.each do |rule|` bit. As a temporary bodge I just assign a value to the issue_id and increment it with each loop. Is there a way to get at the :id value before I iterate over the hashes? Or is my logic here flawed?

Edit 33:
It seems assigning the ID value as below works:

```
xml.issue('id' => outer[0][:id], 'Category' => '2') {
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]", in particular the link at the bottom of the page. Simplify your code and show the minimal needed output you need. Doing that will help you debug and try things, and it'll help make your question more understandable for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule one: Maintain your indentation correctly. There are many great code editors that will help you, either by indenting/outdenting as you write, or by letting you run a formatter. By doing that you can more easily see problems in loops and blocks.

Your desired code example is:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  rule_array.each do |rule|
  xml.Report('Tool' => 'FirewallParserv1') {
    xml.Firewalls {
      xml.Firewall {
        xml.issues {
          xml.issue('id' => rule[:id], 'Category' => '2') {
            end
            xml.Data('mode' => "table") {
              xml.Row {
                xml.columnumn("ACL")
                xml.column("Rule")
                xml.column("Source")
                xml.column("Dest")
                xml.column("Service")
                xml.column("Log")
              }
              rule_array.each do |rule|
              xml.Row {
                xml.column(rule[:aclname])
                xml.column(rule[:Rule])
                xml.column(rule[:Source])
                xml.column(rule[:Destination])
                xml.column(rule[:port])
                xml.column(rule[:Log])
              }
          end
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
end
```

After letting vim reindent it I got:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  rule_array.each do |rule|
    xml.Report('Tool' => 'FirewallParserv1') {
      xml.Firewalls {
        xml.Firewall {
          xml.issues {
            xml.issue('id' => rule[:id], 'Category' => '2') {
  end
  xml.Data('mode' => "table") {
    xml.Row {
      xml.columnumn("ACL")
      xml.column("Rule")
      xml.column("Source")
      xml.column("Dest")
      xml.column("Service")
      xml.column("Log")
    }
    rule_array.each do |rule|
      xml.Row {
        xml.column(rule[:aclname])
        xml.column(rule[:Rule])
        xml.column(rule[:Source])
        xml.column(rule[:Destination])
        xml.column(rule[:port])
        xml.column(rule[:Log])
      }
    end
  }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

which immediately shows there are problems, because XML generating code, like the XML to be output, has to nest correctly.

Adjusting the XML root and the `end` associated with `rule_array` so they nest correctly results in:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Report('Tool' => 'FirewallParserv1') {
    rule_array.each do |rule|
      xml.Firewalls {
        xml.Firewall {
          xml.issues {
            xml.issue('id' => rule[:id], 'Category' => '2') {
              xml.Data('mode' => "table") {
                xml.Row {
                  xml.columnumn("ACL")
                  xml.column("Rule")
                  xml.column("Source")
                  xml.column("Dest")
                  xml.column("Service")
                  xml.column("Log")
                }
                rule_array.each do |rule|
                  xml.Row {
                    xml.column(rule[:aclname])
                    xml.column(rule[:Rule])
                    xml.column(rule[:Source])
                    xml.column(rule[:Destination])
                    xml.column(rule[:port])
                    xml.column(rule[:Log])
                  }
                end
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    end
  }
end
```

But that's not very efficient. With a little tweaking I'd use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'

HEADERS = %w(ACL Rule Source Dest Service Log)
FIELDS = %i(aclname Rule Source Destination port Log)

rule_array = [
  {:id => '1', :aclname => 'inside_access_in', :Rule => '1', :Source => '10.10.10.1',   :Destination => '192.168.1.2',    :port => 'SMTP',   :Log => 'YES'},
  {:id => '2', :aclname => 'inside_access_in', :Rule => '2', :Source => '172.16.2.1',   :Destination => '192.168.100.10', :port => 'HTTP',   :Log => 'NO'},
  {:id => '3', :aclname => 'inside_access_in', :Rule => '3', :Source => '172.16.2.200', :Destination => '10.10.60.1',     :port => 'TELNET', :Log => 'NO'}
]

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Report('Tool' => 'FirewallParserv1') {
    rule_array.each do |rule|
      xml.Firewalls {
        xml.Firewall {
          xml.issues {
            xml.issue('id' => rule[:id], 'Category' => '2') {
              xml.Data('mode' => "table") {
                xml.Row {
                  HEADERS.each do |h|
                    xml.column(h)
                  end
                }
                xml.Row {
                  rule.values_at(*FIELDS).each do |f|
                    xml.column(f)
                  end
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    end
  }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
# >> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# >> <Report Tool="FirewallParserv1">
# >>   <Firewalls>
# >>     <Firewall>
# >>       <issues>
# >>         <issue id="1" Category="2">
# >>           <Data mode="table">
# >>             <Row>
# >>               <column>ACL</column>
# >>               <column>Rule</column>
# >>               <column>Source</column>
# >>               <column>Dest</column>
# >>               <column>Service</column>
# >>               <column>Log</column>
# >>             </Row>
# >>             <Row>
# >>               <column>inside_access_in</column>
# >>               <column>1</column>
# >>               <column>10.10.10.1</column>
# >>               <column>192.168.1.2</column>
# >>               <column>SMTP</column>
# >>               <column>YES</column>
# >>             </Row>
# >>           </Data>
# >>         </issue>
# >>       </issues>
# >>     </Firewall>
# >>   </Firewalls>
# >>   <Firewalls>
# >>     <Firewall>
# >>       <issues>
# >>         <issue id="2" Category="2">
# >>           <Data mode="table">
# >>             <Row>
# >>               <column>ACL</column>
# >>               <column>Rule</column>
# >>               <column>Source</column>
# >>               <column>Dest</column>
# >>               <column>Service</column>
# >>               <column>Log</column>
# >>             </Row>
# >>             <Row>
# >>               <column>inside_access_in</column>
# >>               <column>2</column>
# >>               <column>172.16.2.1</column>
# >>               <column>192.168.100.10</column>
# >>               <column>HTTP</column>
# >>               <column>NO</column>
# >>             </Row>
# >>           </Data>
# >>         </issue>
# >>       </issues>
# >>     </Firewall>
# >>   </Firewalls>
# >>   <Firewalls>
# >>     <Firewall>
# >>       <issues>
# >>         <issue id="3" Category="2">
# >>           <Data mode="table">
# >>             <Row>
# >>               <column>ACL</column>
# >>               <column>Rule</column>
# >>               <column>Source</column>
# >>               <column>Dest</column>
# >>               <column>Service</column>
# >>               <column>Log</column>
# >>             </Row>
# >>             <Row>
# >>               <column>inside_access_in</column>
# >>               <column>3</column>
# >>               <column>172.16.2.200</column>
# >>               <column>10.10.60.1</column>
# >>               <column>TELNET</column>
# >>               <column>NO</column>
# >>             </Row>
# >>           </Data>
# >>         </issue>
# >>       </issues>
# >>     </Firewall>
# >>   </Firewalls>
# >> </Report>
```

which looks kinda sensible, though it's not very efficient XML, but without the missing, yet oh-so-important desired output, it'll have to suffice.

Notice that Nokogiri will take Ruby's symbol keys in the hashes, helping to reduce the visual noise in the hash definitions.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment Tin Man. The hash definitions were purely so I could post some input data for the example, but I'm glad to know a better way to define it! I will post the expected XML format if I can't figure it out with your example.